# Получение позиции udp заголовка

Tags: windows, c, сокет

Вот есть код из мануала Wincap: [ссылка](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut6.html).

И в нем не совсем понятен следующий момент:

```
/* retireve the position of the udp header */
ip_len = (ih->ver_ihl & 0xf) * 4;
uh = (udp_header *) ((u_char*)ih + ip_len);
```

Почему сдвиг только на 20 байт, а не больше? Получается, данные не учитываются, а где тогда они? Я имею ввиду данные 46-1500. Где они расположены?

Получается, что все заголовки идут до 46 байта, а за ними идут данные до 1500 байта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[[[[[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu), откуда у Вас 20, 46 и 1500 байт?

`ip_len` -- максимум `15 * 4 = 60` байт.
`sizeof(*uh)` = 8
`60 + 8 = 68`  -- это максимальное смещение данных (после ip и udp заголовков).
Максимальный размер всего пакета (всех фрагментов вместе со всеми заголовками) -- 65535 байт (`ih->tlen`)

(см. структуру заголовков в, например,  [udp header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) и [ip header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4))

**Обновление**

[[[[[[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu), извините, немного ошибся и обманул Вас.

--

`tlen` в ip заголвке  -- это длина фрагмента, а не всех фрагментов.

Данные  находятся в каждом фрагменте после заголовков. В первом фрагменте, том у которого Fragment offset = 0, после udp заголовка, в остальных сразу после ip.

--

А Вы [описание IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) внимательно прочли?

**Обновление 2**

[[[[[[@xinakapu](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu)](/users/22460/xinakapu), максимальная длина ip header 60 -- это, естественно, минимальная длина = 20 + **Options**.

А про  смещение 14 в коде вашего примера написано:

```
 /* retireve the position of the ip header */
 ih = (ip_header *) (pkt_data +
                      14); //length of ethernet header
```

Про последний вопрос:

```
 И сколько вообще может ещё быть заголовков других протоколов над tcp или udp?
```

не знаю, думаю зависит от того, во что они инкапсулируются на datalink(?) уровне.

Comment: @avp, а данные этих пакетов где?

Comment: @avp, не раз перечитывал), что-то упускаю, видимо. Ну вот 20 байт это минимальная длина ip заголовка, а 60 байт максимальная, но 20 - это заголовок без данных, а 60 тогда что? И по чему нужно было делать сдвиг на 14 байт, чтобы получить ip заголовок, ведь в пакете уже не должно быть ethernet заголовка или для winpcap пакет - тоже самое, что и фрейм? И сколько вообще может ещё быть заголовков других протоколов над tcp или udp?

Comment: Обновил ответ